# Creating a constructor that copies values from parameter into an array called data

Tags: java

Cant figure out how to copy the values from the parameter to the new array data. How would I go about it?

```
class Weight
{

  int[] data;

  // Constructor

  Weight(int[] init)
  {

    // Make data the same length
    // as the array referenced by init.

    data = new; // this part has caused me the most headache (most of the errors)

    // Copy values from the 
    // input data to data.
    for (int index=0; index < init.length; index++)
    {
      data[index] = init[index];
    }
  }

  //Print
  public String to String()
  {
   data   

  }
}
```

Keep getting errors like "array dimension missing"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `length` of `init`

```
int init [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int [] data = new int[init.length];
for (int i = 0; i < init.length; i++) {
    data[i] = init[i];
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
```

**output**

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]